# How to get out all routes [PlaceMark, LineString] in a KML-file when added to Google Maps? [C#]

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

Using this plugin:
https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover.Android.Maps.Utils

I am successfully adding a route to a my Google Map by adding a kml-layer to it. I foreach the lat, lng and via a `Polyline` I create a line! The problem I have is that my KML-file however has multiple routes and with my current code only one of the routes gets added to the map.

How do I adjust my code in order to get every single route stored in my KML-file?

My KML looks like this:

```
  <Folder>
        <name>Tracks</name>
        <description>A list of tracks</description>
        <visibility>1</visibility>            
        <open>0</open>

            <Placemark>
                <visibility>0</visibility>            
                <open>0</open> 
                <styleUrl>#red</styleUrl>
                <name>trackone</name>
                <description>Track no. 1</description>
                <LineString>
                    <extrude>true</extrude>
                    <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode> 
                    <coordinates>
                        10.366653,26.281982,106.075562 10.366759,56.282024,99.504028 10.366846,26.282043,95.945312                            
                    </coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>

    </Folder>
    <Folder>
        <name>Tracks</name>
        <description>A list of tracks</description>
        <visibility>1</visibility>            
        <open>0</open>

            <Placemark>
                <visibility>0</visibility>            
                <open>0</open> 
                <styleUrl>#green</styleUrl>
                <name>tracktwo</name>
                <description>Track no. 2</description>
                <LineString>
                    <extrude>true</extrude>
                    <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode> 
                    <coordinates>
                 10.299386,26.278042,84.550720 
                 10.299453,26.278004,83.942444 
                 10.299522,26.277962,85.036560 
                 10.299572,26.277916,85.828735         

                 </coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
    </Folder>  

    <Folder>
        <name>Waypoints</name>
        <description>A list of waypoints</description>
        <visibility>1</visibility>
        <open>0</open>


        <Placemark>
            <name>name</name>                      
            <visibility>1</visibility>            
            <open>0</open>                        

            <description>
                No info available                </description>       
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>18.581586295142404</longitude>
                <latitude>36.313142255580445</latitude>
                <range>500</range>
                <tilt>45</tilt>
                <heading>0</heading>
            </LookAt>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>
                    10.581586295142404,36.313142255580445                        
                </coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>


        <Placemark>
            <name>name</name>                      
            <visibility>1</visibility>            
            <open>0</open>                        

            <description>
                No info available                </description>       
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>10.378910994617264</longitude>
                <latitude>36.285880605439296</latitude>
                <range>500</range>
                <tilt>45</tilt>
                <heading>0</heading>
            </LookAt>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>
                    11.378910994617264,26.285880605439296                        
                </coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

    </Folder>
```

...Etc with a few more routes in there. My code looks like this:

```
      var container = (KmlContainer)kmlLayer.Containers.Iterator().Next();
      container = (KmlContainer)container.Containers.Iterator().Next();

      var placemark = (KmlPlacemark)container.Placemarks.Iterator().Next();

      if (placemark.HasGeometry && placemark.Geometry is KmlLineString)
      {
      var lineString = placemark.Geometry as KmlLineString;
      var latlngArray = lineString.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList;
      var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
      polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

      using (var builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder())
      {
           foreach (LatLng latLng in latlngArray.ToEnumerable())
           {
                 builder.Include(latLng);
                 polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(latLng.Latitude, latLng.Longitude));
           }
      }

      map.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

I am very new with KML-files but if i understand it correctly do I need to foreach out each single `Cointaner`? I tried to do something along these lines:

```
for (var contain = (KmlContainer)kmlLayer.Containers.Iterator(); contain.Containers.Iterator().Next();)
{
     //add above code in here
}
```

Or something like this where I store it as a list:

```
 List<KmlContainer> cointainers = kmlLayer.Containers.Iterator().Next() as List<KmlContainer>;
```

And add all of the above code inside that for-loop. But the syntax is completely wrong and I am not sure on how to loop out each container.

How do I successfully get out all of the routes in my KML-file and it's coordinates?

UPDATED CODE:

```
        foreach (KmlContainer container in kmlLayer.Containers.ToEnumerable())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("1"); // i reach this

            foreach (var property in container.Properties.ToEnumerable())
            {
                //This is a Java HashMap<string, string> ....
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2"); //i reach this
            }

            if (container.HasPlacemarks)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3"); //i do not reach this which is strange since I use the same KML as b4 that found placemarks.
            }

            foreach (KmlPlacemark placemark in container.Placemarks.ToEnumerable())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("4"); // i do not reach this

                if (placemark.HasGeometry && placemark.Geometry is KmlLineString)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("5"); //not this
                    var lineString = placemark.Geometry as KmlLineString;
                    var latlngArray = lineString.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList;
                    var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

                    using (var builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder())
                    {
                        foreach (LatLng latLng in latlngArray.ToEnumerable())
                        {
                            builder.Include(latLng);
                            polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(latLng.Latitude, latLng.Longitude));
                        }
                    }

                    map.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
                }

                else
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("6"); //not this
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you get this working?

Comment: @SushiHangover No not yet! I put this issue to rest for a bit. I plan to resume with it today

Comment: @SushiHangover I am very unsure on how to write the code because I assume I have to loop out each `Container`, something along these lines `for (KmlContainer containers : container)
   {
                
   }` But I get the syntax wrong no matter how I try it

Comment: I used the KML you posted for that example.... Is `container.HasPlacemarks` true or false at the point?

Comment: @SushiHangover testing that right now `if (container.HasPlacemarks)` one second (i also added my latest code if u check the post in the end under "UPDATED CODE").

Comment: @SushiHangover yeah the container does not have placemarks now even though i use the same KML as b4 which returned placemarks with the old code

Comment: You need to compare the KML that you are using to the sample that you posted as the sample has a single Placemark attached to each Folder (Container).

Comment: When I browse my KML now again it appears that 90 % of the `Folders` have 1 `Placemark` in them but sometimes I see two `Placemarks` in a `Folder` as well. (I updated the KML-text in my post). I have like 30 folders in this KML that I am currently working with.

Comment: With your updated KML is still works fine for me, see the updated output in my answer....

Comment: it has some `Folders` as u can see so most likely something in the file must be messed up. i will take a look at it now to see if i see anything strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A KML `Folder` will be turned into `KmlContainer`, you need to loop over all the `KMLLayer` containers and extract the elements you need:

Note: this is using Linq's `ToEnumerable` to convert the Java `Iterator`

#### Example:

```
if (kmlLayer.Containers != null)
{
    foreach (KmlContainer container in kmlLayer.Containers.ToEnumerable())
    {
        foreach (var property in container.Properties.ToEnumerable())
        {
            //This is a Java HashMap<string, string> ....
            Log.Debug(Constants.TAG, $"{property.ToString()} : {container.GetProperty(property.ToString())}"); 
        }
        foreach (KmlPlacemark placemark in container.Placemarks.ToEnumerable())
        {
            Log.Debug(Constants.TAG, placemark.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
SomeTag: visibility : 1
SomeTag: name : Tracks
SomeTag: description : A list of tracks
SomeTag: open : 0
SomeTag: Placemark{
SomeTag:  style id=#red,
SomeTag:  inline style=null
SomeTag: }
SomeTag: visibility : 1
SomeTag: name : Tracks
SomeTag: description : A list of tracks
SomeTag: open : 0
SomeTag: Placemark{
SomeTag:  style id=#green,
SomeTag:  inline style=null
SomeTag: }
```

#### To Iterate Container w/ Containers:

```
if (kmlLayer.HasContainers)
{
    void IterateProperties(KmlContainer containers)
    {
        foreach (var property in containers.Properties.ToEnumerable())
            Log.Debug(Constants.TAG, $"{property.ToString()} : {containers.GetProperty(property.ToString())}");
    }
    void IterateLineString(KmlLineString lineString)
    {
        var latlngArray = lineString.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList;
        foreach (LatLng item in latlngArray.ToEnumerable())
        {
            Log.Debug(Constants.TAG, $"{item.Latitude}:{item.Longitude}");
        }
    }
    void IteratePlaceMarks(KmlContainer container)
    {
        foreach (KmlPlacemark placemark in container.Placemarks.ToEnumerable())
        {
            IterateProperties(container);
            Log.Debug(Constants.TAG, placemark.ToString());
            if (placemark.HasGeometry & placemark.Geometry is KmlLineString)
                IterateLineString(placemark.Geometry as KmlLineString);
        }
    }
    void IterateSubContainers(KmlContainer container)
    {
        IterateProperties(container);
        IteratePlaceMarks(container);
        if (container.HasContainers)
        {
            foreach (KmlContainer subContainer in container.Containers.ToEnumerable())
                IterateSubContainers(subContainer);
        }
    }

    foreach (KmlContainer container in kmlLayer.Containers.ToEnumerable())
        IterateSubContainers(container);
}
```

Comment: I tested the code but the code does not reach inside the last foreach loop: `foreach (KmlPlacemark placemark in container.Placemarks.ToEnumerable())` it's in that loop I build the latlng and create the polylines.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Your KML has subcontainers as your top level container is `Document` that contains `Folders`, not a collection of top-level `Folders`, see my updated routine : *`To Iterate Container w/ Containers:`* That will get you access to all the LineStrings within each Placemark

Comment: Dang, ur the man! So sorry that I am not that good at reading KML/XML-files. I only have experience with JSON as of yet but I will read more about XML/KML now so I get that fully locked down. Once again, thanks so much!