# Unsuccessful in getting out KML-file placemarks when looping out an arraylist in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been working with a project that uses google maps and kml-routes. This project worked successfully a few months ago but now when I debug it the app crashes with the following errormessage:

`System.ArgumentNullException`

If I comment away...

```
foreach (var data in lineString.ToEnumerable())
{

}
```

...then the app successfully runs meaning that it can’t get the values inside ”Placemarks”.

This is the code:

```
public async void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
     InvokeOnMapReadyBaseClassHack(googleMap);
     map = googleMap;
     layer = new KmlLayer(map, Resource.Raw.mykmlfile, Android.App.Application.Context); 
}

async void MoveCameraToKmlTwo(KmlLayer kmlLayer)
{
        var list = new List<object>();

        if (kmlLayer.HasContainers)
        {
            void IterateProperties(KmlContainer containers)
            {
                foreach (var property in containers.Properties.ToEnumerable())
                {

                }
            }
            void IterateLineString(ArrayList lineString)
            {
                //when i try to get out the data in here i get the crash
                foreach (var data in lineString.ToEnumerable())
                {

                }
            }

            void IteratePlaceMarks(KmlContainer container)
            {
                foreach (KmlPlacemark placemark in container.Placemarks.ToEnumerable())
                {
                    IterateProperties(container);
                    if (placemark.HasGeometry & placemark.Geometry is KmlLineString)
                    {
                        IterateLineString(placemark.Geometry.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList);

                    }
                }
            }

            void IterateSubContainers(KmlContainer container)
            {
                IterateProperties(container);
                IteratePlaceMarks(container);
                if (container.HasContainers)
                {
                    foreach (KmlContainer subContainer in container.Containers.ToEnumerable())
                        IterateSubContainers(subContainer);
                }
            }

            foreach (KmlContainer container in kmlLayer.Containers.ToEnumerable())
                IterateSubContainers(container);

        }
}
```

My kml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">

<Document>
<name>Routes</name>
<description></description>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <open>1</open>

    <Style id="dark_green">
        <LineStyle>
        <color>C8008C14</color>
        <width>4</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>

    <Style id="route_dark_blue">
        <LineStyle>
        <color>96F01414</color>
        <width>4</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>


  <Folder>
        <name>Tracks</name>
        <description>A list of tracks</description>
        <visibility>1</visibility>            
        <open>0</open>                                      
            <Placemark>
                <visibility>0</visibility>            
                <open>0</open> 
                <styleUrl>#red</styleUrl>
                <name>Around the lake</name>
                <description>Track no. 1</description>
                <LineString>
                    <extrude>true</extrude>
                    <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode> 
                    <coordinates>
                        7.366653,42.281982,106.075562 7.366759,42.282024,99.504028 7.366846,42.282043,95.945312 7.366909,42.282085,94.900269 7.366982,42.282116,94.186218 7.367039,42.282150,90.530640 7.367124,42.282135,87.749268 7.367111,42.282192,89.794800 7.367088,42.282242,90.636597 7.367079,42.282299,89.214539                             
                    </coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>                          
    </Folder>
  </Document>
 </kml>
```

Comment: is this cast valid?  placemark.Geometry.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList

Comment: The code runs so assume so yes. I also did it like this before with the same result (if u check the bookmarked answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786038/how-to-get-out-all-routes-placemark-linestring-in-a-kml-file-when-added-to-go

Comment: "it runs" is not a good answer.  It appears to be returning a null, which is breaking your app.  Something may have changed in the API that is causing it to break now.  I suggest you actually test it to verify that it works.

Comment: If i type `lineString.IsEmpty` in the log it gives me: `System.NullReferenceException`, "Object not set to an instance of an object". If i write out `placemark.Geometry.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList` it gives me whitespace values in the log (empty rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this cast

```
placemark.Geometry.GeometryJavaObject() as Java.Util.ArrayList
```

Instead you should use

```
placemark.Geometry.GeometryJavaObject().JavaCast<Java.Util.ArrayList>()
```

That is if you are 100% certain what you get back is a `ArrayList`.

You can always figure out whether you need to use `JavaCast<T>()` by trying to cast explicitly. Why `JavaCast` works while a normal cast doesn't [can be read about in the Xamarin Documentation about `JavaCast<T>()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast%3CTResult%3E/). In short terms: it is a hack...

Comment: Code runs without an exception but when i try to foreach loop out the content it is empty. I will look if i need an arraylist or not now

Comment: What do u mean by `JavaCast<T>()` What does `T` stand for in this case?

Comment: `T` is the type you want to cast to, just like in the example.